# How to refresh parent page using javascript / asp.net in mozilla firefox browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, cross-browser, refresh

The function window.opener.location.reload(); is working fine with IE but not refreshing parent page in mozilla firefox browser. please tell me how to refresh parent page in cross browser/browser independent.

i have got this function:

```
Shared Sub CloseMyWindow()
Dim tmpStr As String = ""
tmpStr += "window.open('','_parent','');window.close();"
tmpStr += "window.opener.location.reload();"  

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>" + tmpStr + "</script>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: This should work fine in Firefox (Maybe with the restriction that the parent URL still needs to be the same that opened the window, can't remember right now). Do you get any error messages in the error console?

Comment: no error .. and i have checked it with simple application.. but its not working

Comment: There's something you're not telling us.  Please post a complete example.  `window.opener.location.reload()` works in Firefox.  Perhaps you're trying to go cross-domain, or you have JavaScript turned off, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/remote3.shtml) and maybe try an alternative ways to refresh the page (just to be sure ;)) like

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href
```

as the reload way seems not to work in Firefox (actually the opener property should)

Try to install Firebug or some other diagnostic tool to see whether the opener property is not null and better understand the problem. Firebug is awesome anyway :)

Comment: It's just an alternative way to the usage of opener that you might want to try if the opener property is the problem. It could be the reload function or anything else.. you never know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

by passing through the true you will avoid the problem of the popup firefox and most browsers display.  This does have an affect though by reloading all images, css and js from the server and not from cache.